# Ibm Rad 9.7 and EGit - No repository found

Tags: egit, rad

I downloaded EGit p2 repository ZIP ([5.7.0.202003110725-r](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/)) to install it offline. Though, the installation ends failing with the following error :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=IBM Software Delivery Platform com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.ejb,3.1.1.v201204261316
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,3.0.0.v201112011016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.bind,2.2.0.v201105210648
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.catalina,7.0.56.v201503170330
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.logging,1.2.0.v20180409-1502
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.coyote,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.el,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.jasper,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.juli.extras,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.tomcat.api,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.tomcat.util,7.0.56.v201412180755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.update.core,3.2.700.v20140518-1928
```

Same error occurs if installing via eclipse marketplace.

I'm using IBM RAD 9.7

Comment: RAD already bundles EGit, have you tried installing it via Installation Manager?

Comment: Yes i did, but the installation is not working. That's why i downloaded it seperately. According to my research there is no EGit plugin for the 9.7 version anyway.

Comment: RAD 9.7 is based on Eclipse Oxygen, according to the EGit FAQ https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ even the latest EGit version should be compatible, I recommend opening a PMR with IBM